# What is efficient way to use $in query in pymongo in case of very large list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo

As in pymongo we can use $in and pass list to it. But in case of very large list it may run out of memory. So how to avoid it ? Can I pass generator instead list ?

Comment: You could process that list in batches. Break it up in chunks of, say 100 or 1000 ids and process those separately.

Comment: "Can I pass generator instead" - even if it were possible, don't you think you'd run out of memory when receiving the response?

Comment: @Sergio Tulentsev  we can paginate the result. As it returns iterator

Comment: Dividing list in parts is good idea BTW

Answer (score 1):

> What is efficient way to use $in query in pymongo in case of very large list?

MongoDB limits the size of a query to 16 MB (via the BSON document size limit). Therefore, technically, MongoDB is *already* efficient for large queries in that excessively large queries are prohibited.

If you are asking how to efficiently *query* your database for documents where the query set is large (not necessarily by using $in, nor requiring a predetermined condition), there are several options:

- Put the query into a collection as documents, use the aggregation pipeline.
- Change your data model so that instead of (or in addition to) an exhaustive enumeration of values you store a trait that is common to those values, then query by that trait.